# React router URL don't work when refreshing or writing manually. and getting html data instead of JSON data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on a MERN website where I'm using React-router and it works fine while I'm clicking on link buttons, but when I refresh my webpage it does not load what I want. React router URL doesn't work when refreshing or writing manually. so I saw many solutions for that problem. I used one solution that is to catch every get request in server.js and send index.html file.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));

app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});

 }
```

This process worked perfectly and solved the react-router problem but on the client-side, I was getting some data by sending Axios get request.

```
useEffect(() => {
          
        axios
            .get("/posts")
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.data);
      //result.data contains index.html file instead of json data
                
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);
```

the response of that get request should have get JSON data but it gets index.html file. I know it gets that index.html file because I send the index.html file when catching all requests in server.js.

```
app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

but if I remove that line of code then I face React router URL doesn't work error when refreshing or writing URL manually.
what I want is to solve the react-router problem and also get JSON data from that request and use that data to map through those data. Here are my server.js, App.js, and Posts.js code

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));

    app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
    });
}
mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Database connected");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Database error ${err.message}`);
    });

const postsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
    },
});

const Posts = new mongoose.model("Posts", postsSchema);

app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
    Posts.find({}, (error, post) => {
        if (error) {
            res.json(error.message);
        } else {
            res.json(post);
        }
    });
});


    
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log("App started in port 5000");
});
```

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Posts from "./Posts";
import Header from "./Header";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    
                    <Route exact path="/posts" component={Posts} />
                    
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Posts.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Posts() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get("/posts")
            .then((result) => {
                setPosts(result.data);
                console.log(result.data);
               //result.data contains index.html file instead of JSON data
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container mt-5">
            <div className="row">
                {posts.map((post) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="col-sm-3" key={post._id}>
                            <h6>{post.title}</h6>
                            <p>{post.description}</p>

                            <Link className="nav-link active" to={`/post/${post._id}`}>
                                Read More
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Posts;
```

Please help me if you know what is the problem with my code. and how can I get JSON data instead of that index.html file

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");
//const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); not necessary
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());

/*if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));

    app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
    });
}*/
mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Database connected");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Database error ${err.message}`);
    });

const postsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
    },
});

const Posts = new mongoose.model("Posts", postsSchema);

// Static Files Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"client","bluild")))

// Routes
app.use("/posts", (req, res)=>{
    Posts.find({}, (error, post) => {
        if (error) {
            res.json(error.message);
        } else {
            res.json(post);
        }
    });
})
app.use("/*", (req, res)=>{res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"public/index.html"))}) /*always at the end*/

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log("App started in port 5000");
});
```

That should work, now I'd like to give you some tips.

- Express in last versions include body-parser
  If you are going to use 1 server that handles client-side + server-side (i mean without using create-react-app and creating other server to make requests):
- Fist, you have to declear the static folder where you gonna put you bundle made with react (in your case, I think it's index.js).
- It's not necessary to re-send the bundle for a route that does not exist, you can send a json to the client-side (res.json({Status: 'NotFound'})) and there you'll have to show to user that page don't exist (using react, create a component NotFound  and make sure it's the last route in the routing) or just send res.status(401). Though, this isn't necessary if you use the next point.
- In react-router, you should use "HashRouter as Router" instead of "BrowserRouter as Router", it's a little bit dificult to explain you can find out about it.

Comment: Thanks for your response... 
I tried your code, it works fine in development. but when I deployed it in Heroku it didn't work. then I took your advice and used Hash Router and it solved my problem but it looked ugly on the URL. 
Then after someday of testing and research. i used those line of code
`if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
 app.use(express.static("client/build"));
 app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
 });
}` 

I Put those lines of code at the bottom of my server.js file and it worked for me.
Thanks.